# How to implement ssis error handling when source files are integrating data into hundreds of tables?

Tags: error-handling, ssis

In the SSIS package, the source files are dumping data into 100s of tables with thousands of columns. Package breaks very often mainly due to truncation error. Once that column is fixed that works fine. Considering thousands of columns which column will break next that is completely unpredictable. If there are few tables i can redirect the error rows but with hundreds of tables, it is not feasible.
Is there any way to do error handling in such kind of situation? Thanks

Comment: Hundreds of tables, thousands of columns... sounds like a question of DB design and ETL design. First of all, why are you using ONE package for all tables? Wouldn't it be better to split things up? However, except simply redirecting the rows you could add a script component which then adds corresponding logging info into a table - basing on this you can analyse the faulty columns and so on.

Comment: https://www.leapfrogbi.com/etl-design-patterns-the-foundation/